# Where did JSONConfiguration go in Jersey 2.5.x?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I'm porting some server code from jersey 1.1 version to 2.5.1  and I can't seem to find JSONConfiguration.

Is JAXB context resolver no longer part of Jersey 2.5 or has the group id changed ? Is there another mechanism to implement a ContextResolver ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a dumb question.. I'll answer it in case others are under pressure to complete a port..

The Jersey/Jackson *ContextResovler* using *JAXBContext* has been removed. The new model for the  *ContextResovler* uses the *ObjectMapper*.

For an example see the [ObjectMapperProvider](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.5.1/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyObjectMapperProvider.java) in the Jersey examples directory.

Comment: so what will be the equivalent of these now?

config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);