# jersey: JSONJAXBContext (from jersey 1) replacement in jersey 2?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I noticed that `JSONJAXBContext` (from Jersey 1) is gone in Jersey 2. So, what is the alternative way in Jersey 2 to marshal/unmarshal JAXB objects into JSON?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

JBT
Your question is already answered in : [Where did JSONConfiguration go in Jersey 2.5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220760/where-did-jsonconfiguration-go-in-jersey-2-5-x)
You have to use an ObjectMapperProvider :
https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.5.1/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyObjectMapperProvider.java