# Migration of JSONJAXBContext jersey 1.x to 2.x

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I want to upgrade my jersey version to 2.x from 1.x.
In my code I had:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
private static final Class<?>[] classes = {
        A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class, E.class,
        F.class, G.class
};
private JAXBContext context;

public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
    context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural()
            .humanReadableFormatting(true).rootUnwrapping(true).build(),
            classes);
}

public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
    return context;
}
}
```

But JSONJAXBContext and JSONConfiguration are not defined in jersey 2.x.
How can I make the change accordingly?

The question [Where did JSONConfiguration go in Jersey 2.5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220760/where-did-jsonconfiguration-go-in-jersey-2-5-x) is not answering my question because it does not explain how do I add my class which I want to return as output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did JSONConfiguration go in Jersey 2.5.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220760/where-did-jsonconfiguration-go-in-jersey-2-5-x)

Comment: @jah not too helpful since it looks like using completely different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for this. You either are going to use MOXy or Jackson as your JSON provider in Jersey 2.x. For the latter, you configure with `MoxyJsonConfig`. For Jackson, you use `ObjectMapper`. Figure out which provider you are using, and configure the according object. Both can be configured in a `ContextResolver` like you're currently doing.

As far as your current configurations

1. You won't need to configure any classes with either of these.
2. Unwrapped objects are serialized by default.
3. And to pretty print you would do the following

   Jackson

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
   ```

   MOXy

   ```
   MoxyJsonConfig config = new MoxyJsonConfig()
           .setFormattedOutput(true);
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by Unwrapped objects?
So basicly I can use this example <a  href="https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.5.1/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyObjectMapperProvider.java"> ObjectMapperProvider</a> and I am good?

Comment: `{ "ObjectType": { "key":"value"}}` == wrapped root value. `{"key":"value"}` == not wrapped. I see you have a configuration to unwrap the root value, that's why I mentioned it. The native implementation for Jersey 1.x was to wrap it.

Comment: But anyway, looking at your other question, it looks like you are using jettison as the provider. I am not quite sure how to configure that, and I would actually recommend using Jackson instead. You can change the `jersey-media-json-jettison` to `jersey-media-json-jackson`, then yes, you can use a `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`